# URL Rewrite in IIS 7.5 not working

Tags: iis-7.5, redirect, rewrite

I am trying to redirect all http traffic to https as the site requires SSL.

For example, if someone navigates to http://site.com or http://www.site.com I want to redirect the user to https://www.site.com

Right now the user gets a 403.4 Forbidden error - The page you are trying to access is secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

I've tried a number of different URL rewrite rules but none of them seem to work.  In fact nothing seems to be happening different at all, almost like the module isn't even working properly.

First, is my rule correct?  And if so, what else could be preventing this from working properly?

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect all http traffic to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Your condition is expecting the input to be `{HTTPS}`. Try removing that condition.

Comment: Just remove the condition or change it?

Comment: I would just remove, it is asking for a condition you do not need.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately IIS is still not redirecting after removing that condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

And SSL needs to be off apparently.

Not sure if the  and  tags are appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, that was the hold up.  I had require SSL checked.  Once I unchecked it, the URL rewrites fired correctly, thanks.

Comment: Just to add to an old thread.... I had same issue, yet SSL was unchecked So I checked it.. apply
Uncheck .... apply Works now like a charm

Comment: This worked for me. Mathias R. Jessen references this as the first of two ways to approach this problem. http://serverfault.com/questions/617204/url-redirect-not-working-in-iis-7-5